# Tried to run the default flutter application but facing this error

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources' (type 'LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask').

  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask' property 'androidJarInput.androidJar' specifies file 'C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar' which doesn't exist.

    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
    2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist for more details about this problem.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s

This is the output I got after running flutter doctor -v
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 3.0.4 at C:\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 85684f9300 (3 weeks ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
• Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
• Dart version 2.17.5
• DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.2.3)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.2.32526.322
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

[√] VS Code (version 1.69.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.44.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.795]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.49

[√] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!

[Tried running flutter run -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Kvd.png)

Comment: are you running on emulator ? if yes then make sure you have SDK 32 installed

Comment: I am running it on physical device.

Comment: make sure you have SDK installed

Comment: you can check the content here C:\Users\samir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\ try to check what folders do you have here. also make sure you adjust your build.gradle file with minimumSDK accordingly.

Comment: The sdk is installed and it is the latest version available

Comment: please attach the screenshot, also share the output of "flutter doctor -v"

Comment: try to run your application using "flutter run -v" and share the output

Comment: I have edited the question and added all the things you requested please tell if you have any solution

Comment: Please refer to the solution which worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73339581/4527624