# i am facing this issue while debugging it on emulator

Tags: flutter

problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources' (type 'LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask').

- In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask' property 'androidJarInput.androidJar' specifies file 'C:\Users\NISHANT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31\android.jar' which doesn't exist.

  Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.

Comment: is this the whole error?

Comment: @waqadarshad yes its the whole error i am facing while debugging

Comment: try downloading android 31 from the Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> select SDK Platforms and check Android 12.0 and click apply and let it download and install and then try restarting Android studio and/or the laptop/PC if required and then try again.
If this doesn't work out, please let me know.

Comment: Edit: If this doesn't work out, try downloading and adding this to the designated address: https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-list/blob/master/android.jar/api-level-31/android.jar

Comment: if any of these works out, please let me know and I'll add it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I'll check and let you know @WaqadArshad

Comment: the first solution worked , thanks @WaqadArshad

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer that I wrote so that it can help others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Try downloading android 31 from the Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> select SDK Platforms and check Android 12.0 and click apply and let it download and install and then try restarting Android studio and/or the laptop/PC if required and then try again.

Solution 2: If Solution 1 doesn't work out, try downloading and adding [API 31 android.jar](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-list/blob/master/android.jar/api-level-31/android.jar) to the designated address: (C:\Users\NISHANT\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-31)

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me. Thank you @Waqad